# gradle debug main class

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gradle

I have class

```
public class Main {

    private static final String DEFAULT_PACKAGE = "com/project/";
    private static final String XLS_FILE = DEFAULT_PACKAGE + "rule.xls";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RuleRunner ruleRunner = new RuleRunner();

        // build fact
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName("John");
        p.setCash(100);

        ruleRunner.runRules(new Object[] { p }, XLS_FILE, RuleType.XLS);
    }
}
```

Which is set as main for `application` plugin.

In Eclipse I set a breakpoint there.
but how to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From application plugin section of [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html):

> You can launch the application in debug mode with `gradle run --debug-jvm`

This will run you main class and listen on port 5005. Configure Eclipse run/debug configuration and attach sources.

[More](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-you-attach-a-debugger-to-gradle-so-that-i-can-debug-it-running-a-task/7526) discussion on debugging (tests)